# Android Facebook SDK dialog freeze before dismiss

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I've a little issue and google doesn't helped me...

i integrated in my application facebook sdk, and then when i try to dismiss feed dialog the application freezes with loading progress dialog visible, and i must kill the application.

If i tap on "post" the message is successfully posted on the my facebook wall, but the dialog freeze and i can't do anything.

This is my simple code to call the feed dialog:

```
this.facebook.dialog(this.context, "feed", new HTFeedDialogListener(this.context, success, error));
```

When i try to dismiss the dialog with "cancel" or with "Post" In FbDialog.java the overrided method onPageStarted is called with the following url as parameter:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed
```

but the method onPageFinished or shouldOverrideUrlLoading is never called.

Anyone has noticed about this strange behavior? I'm using Galxy s2 and Galaxy tab 10.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused because i use facebook feed dialog in my external android library. To solve it i run dialg on main ui thread with this code:

```
mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
 public void run() {
         mFacebook.dialog(getContext() , "feed",  feedParams, new SimpleDialogListener()));
    }
});
```